# Memory Leak with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, serialization, memory-leaks, nsmutabledictionary

Confused to why this line of code is causing a memory leak:

```
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:rawCourseArray options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:&format error:NULL];
```

Any suggestions on a fix is much appreciated!

Regards,
B

Comment: do you release `d` before you exit the scope of the method where this code is?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response:  

When I try releasing "d" my app crashes.  But when I check leaks from the Performance tool it shows:   Leaked Object: NSCFString; Responsible Library: Foundation; Responsible Frame: NSPropertyListSerialization

Comment: propertyListWithData returns an autoreleased object - so you shouldn't release d manually

Comment: Still getting a leak with the above code.  Any ideas will help considerably!  Not sure what to do.  The leak maybe regarding the error.  But I am not sure how to release the error... ???

Comment: Like @Kenny said, there's no leak. Post code surrounding these two lines and we may be able to track down the leak.

Also, you are misusing the format enum.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use property?

```
self.d = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:rawCourseArray options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:&format error:NULL];
```

I alos encountered the similar leak an resolved it using property (i.e. self.d)

Comment: Tried self.d but it gave a syntax error.  Are you sure that was your solution?  thx

Comment: Just noticed... The new version of this code I am currently using differs in the way I declare the variable.  I changed it from  "NSMutableDictionary *d" to "id d"... I will try tonight changing it back to "NSMutableDictionary *d" and trying the "self.d" again.